# Calculating On Time Delivery with Complex Rules (Excluding weekends)

Tags: php, mysql, list, summary

I'm having trouble creating an efficient MySQL query that calculates On Time Delivery based on specific rules.  I am also open to a PHP solution if it's more efficient.  I'm still learning so please take it easy on me.

Here's my Jobs table:

Jobs Table:

```
+--------------+
|  Field       |
+--------------+
|  Job_ID      | 
|  Customer_ID |
|  Rep_ID      |<- Used for Filtering
|  Premium     |<- Tinyint(1) (0 by default, 1 if Premium)
|  Due_Date    |
|  Ship_Date   |
+--------------+
```

Here are the Rules for calculating On Time Delivery:

```
*Working Day = Weekdays (I would like to exclude holidays but for now, let's just go with all Weekdays)

Rule 1: (Simple) If a Job is of the Premium Type:
    Ship_Date before Due_Date = Early
    Ship_Date same as Due_Date = On Time
    Ship_Date after Due_Date = Late

Rule 2: (Complex) If a Job is of the Standard Type:
    Ship_Date before Due_Date minus 2 Working Days = Early
    Ship_Date within Due_Date minus 2 Working Days and Due_Date plus 1 Working Day = On Time
    Ship_Date after Due_Date plus 1 Working Day = Late

Example:
   Due_Date=Nov 9, 2012 and Premium=0
   if Ship_Date is Nov 1, 2012 then Status is Early by (4) Days
   if Ship_Date is Nov 6, 2012 then Status is Early by (1) Day
   if Ship_Date is Nov 7, 2012 then Status is On Time 
   if Ship_Date is Nov 12, 2012 then Status is On Time 
   if Ship_Date is Nov 13, 2012 then Status is Late by (1) Day
   if Ship_Date is Nov 20, 2012 then Status is Late by (6) Days
```

Desired Report Format Example:
I'm trying to get the number Early, On Time and Late Jobs at the Header.  The Order is by the Ship Date.

```
On Time Delivery Report    

October (Early: 1 / On Time: 2 / Late: 0) 
+------+-----------+---------+----------+-----------+-----------+------+--------+ 
| Job #| Cust Name | Premium | Due_Date | Ship_Date |Qty Shipped|Status|DaysDiff|
+------+-----------+---------+----------+-----------+-----------+------+--------+
 <List all jobs shipped in October> 


November (Early: 0 / On Time: 3 / Late: 0)
+------+-----------+---------+----------+-----------+-----------+------+--------+ 
| Job #| Cust Name | Premium | Due_Date | Ship_Date |Qty Shipped|Status|DaysDiff|
+------+-----------+---------+----------+-----------+-----------+------+--------+
 <List all jobs shipped in November>
```

Can someone suggest a solution for me?  If so, should I let MySQL or PHP do most of the work?  I'm looking for an elegant solution that would also take into account Rules 1 and 2 from above.

Should I denormalize my table and store on time delivery status and day differences to improve performance?  I'm sorry for the long post.  I'm still learning and I would appreciate some advice.

Comment: looks more like a 'question' for code review.

Comment: Two different problems really. Reworking the query so you can bolt in the other parts and leave it maintainable versus optimising (an index on Month(ShipDate) for instance). If you optimise this chnaging it to make it more maintainable is likely to make the optimisation redundant, or possibly counter-productive. Peronally I'd get the other bits in first and then start hacking away at it, as any optimisation for maintainability or performance is likely to be premature.

Comment: I think I've put too much info here.  The most important part for me is determining whether or not it's late, on time or early based on the rules above and the difference (number of working days).